# React Material UI - Snackbar closes when Dialog closes but its not supposed to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Material ui dialog closes the snackbar along with it.

This is a weird problem so I created a demo to demonstrate the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-v20w3

I am passing states from parent to child so the parent state can update based on the child

```
 <Child openDialog={openDialog} setOpenDialog={setOpenDialog} />
```

In the child, I am using these as below

```
export default function Child({openDialog, setOpenDialog}) {
```

The button in the child is supposed to close only the dialog but it closes snackbar too.

```
  <button 
  onClick={() => dialogClick()}
  >Click this dialog button
  </button>
```

Line 12 in the child has `setOpenSnack("true");`    This only works when I comment out line 13 `setOpenDialog(false);`

```
  const dialogClick = (event) => {
    setMsg("This should close dialog only and open the snackbar");
    setOpenSnack(true);
    setOpenDialog(false);
  };
```

This behavior is only when I split it into child and parent.

In short, why does `setOpenSnack(true);` in the child not work?

Comment: `Snackbar`'s `open` prop expects boolean. You should use `setOpenSnack(true)` instead of `setOpenSnack("true")`.

Comment: @bertdida Sure.  I updated the demo. That does not fix the issue. Good catch though

Comment: Basically you want to show the snackbar when the dialog is closed?

Comment: @bertdida I have simplified to show the issue but yes, the snackbar should not disappear when dialog is closed. They are separate elements. Seems like a bug but not sure.

Comment: Your `Snackbar` is sitting inside `Dialog`. When the `Dialog` unmounts/hidden, your `Snackbar` will also be unmounted.

Comment: @bertdida So sounds like I need to move snackbar to parent? The child actually does a datbase put and upon success, I need to show a message in snackbar. So basically child now needs to pass a message to the parent's snackbar. I didnt think that worked in react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `Snackbar` to your parent component so that it's not dependent on `Dialog`'s lifecycle.

**App.js**

```js
import DialogBody from "./child";

function App() {
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
  const [openSnack, setOpenSnack] = useState(false);
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("nothing");

  function doApiCall(formData) {
    // do your API calls here
    console.log(formData);

    // when done hide dialog, show snackbar
    setOpenDialog(false);
    setOpenSnack(true);
  }

  const fireOnClick = (event) => {
    setMsg("you clicked a button");
    setOpenDialog(true);
  };

  const handleCloseSnack = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }

    setOpenSnack(false);
  };

  function Alert(props) {
    return <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant="filled" {...props} />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>click button below to open dialog</h3>

      <button onClick={() => fireOnClick()}>Click me</button>

      <Dialog open={openDialog}>
        <DialogTitle>This is a dialog</DialogTitle>
        <DialogBody doApiCall={doApiCall} />
      </Dialog>

      <Snackbar
        open={openSnack}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        onClose={handleCloseSnack}
      >
        <Alert onClose={handleCloseSnack} severity="error">
          {msg}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child.js**

```js
export default function DialogBody({ doApiCall }) {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

  function onChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={name} onChange={onChange} />
      <button onClick={() => doApiCall({ name })}>
        Click this dialog button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Our `DialogBody` component only accepts a prop called `doApiCall` from our parent, which is invoked by clicking the `Click this dialog button`.

`doApiCall` might be an asynchronous call to your backends API which when resolves will hide the dialog and sets the snackbar to open.

[image: Edit React Hooks Counter Demo]

Comment: Is it possible to pass something from child to parent using doApicall? The dialog is a form which when submitted, posts text from the form using api. Unless I can grab that text from the dialog form and give it to parent, I cant do the api call in parent.

Comment: Sure thing. I updated my answer.  `doApiCall` will now accept a `formData` parameter. :)

Comment: I added a text field in `DialogBody`, which kinda demonstrate what you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

When the dialog is closed, the Child component is dismantled. This justifies the disappearance of the Snack.
Try this to see:

index.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import Child from "./child";
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";
import MuiAlert from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";


import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("nothing");
  const [openSnack, setOpenSnack] = useState(false);
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
  //Close snackbar except when clickaway

  const fireOnClick = (event) => {
    setMsg("you clicked a button");
    setOpenDialog(true);
    //setOpenSnack(true);
  };

  const snackState = (value) => {
          setOpenSnack(value)
  }

  const snackMessage = (value) => {
    setMsg(value)
}

  const handleCloseSnack = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }
    setOpenSnack(false);
  };

  function Alert(props) {
    return <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant="filled" {...props} />;
  }

  const closeDialogOnly = (event) => {
    setMsg("you closed dialog only");
    setOpenDialog(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>click button below to open dialog</h3>

      <button onClick={() => fireOnClick()}>Click me</button>

      <Dialog onClose={closeDialogOnly} open={openDialog}>
        <DialogTitle>This is a dialog</DialogTitle>
        <Child snackbarStat={snackState} snackMessage={snackMessage} setOpenDialog={setOpenDialog} />
      </Dialog>

      <Snackbar
        open={openSnack}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        onClose={handleCloseSnack}
      >
        <Alert onClose={handleCloseSnack} severity="error">
          {msg}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </div>
  );
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

child.js

```
    import React from "react";


export default function Child({ snackbarStat, setOpenDialog, snackMessage }) {

  const dialogClick = (event) => {
    snackMessage("snackMessage")
    snackbarStat(true);
    setOpenDialog(false);
  };


  return (
    <div className="child">
      <button onClick={() => dialogClick()}>Click this dialog button</button>

      <p>
        {" "}
        Clicking the button should close dialog but why is it closing the
        snackbar also? <br />
        The snack bar opens for one second and disappears.
        <br />
        setOpenSnack("true") lines is useless when dialog is false.
      </p>

      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ahh, the reason makes sense. How can I pass a message from child to the parent snackbar if I move it to the parent? I thought react only works to pass props from parent to child. In my case, in the dialog, there is a form that updates database. Upon success, snackbar need to get a message.

Comment: You just have to follow to create a function as I did with **snackState** to pass it as a prop to the child in order to be able to retrieve the message

Comment: I have modified my response so that it takes into account the message that will come from the child

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the `Snackbar` in the parent component because when placing it in child component, it will disappear whenever the child is unmounted

Moreover, if you want to set the message, just pass the `setMsg` to the child component and do the job

```js
export default function Child({
  openDialog,
  setOpenDialog,
  setMsg,
  setOpenSnack
}) {
  const dialogClick = (event) => {
    setMsg("you closed from CHILD");
    setOpenSnack(true);
    setOpenDialog(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="child">
      <button onClick={() => dialogClick()}>Click this dialog button</button>
      <p>
        ...
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hooks Counter Demo]